# Angular 2 validation on Hotel Amenity Open Time and Close Time

Tags: angular

I am new to angular, so need some help. I have two fields open and close time of hotel amenities. There is no validation as such. Until user select none of them it must pass the validation but if user select any of them, then user must select another field also and vice verse.

Here is .html code

```
<div class="form-group row">
     <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].valid && (addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].dirty || addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].touched)}">
            <div class="form-material">
              <label for="amenity-edit-opens">Opens at</label>
              <div id='amenity-edit-opens' class='input-group date'>
                <input formControlName="open_time" type='text' class="form-control" id="open_add_amenity" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div [ngClass]="{'help-block animated fadeInDown':addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].hasError('required') && addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].touched}" *ngIf="addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].hasError('required') && addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['open_time'].touched">Please select open at.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].valid && (addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].dirty || addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].touched)}">
            <div class="form-material">
              <label for="amenity-edit-closes">Closes at</label>
              <div id="amenity-edit-closes" class='input-group date'>
                <input formControlName="close_time" type='text' class="form-control" id="close_add_amenity" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div [ngClass]="{'help-block animated fadeInDown':addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].hasError('required') && addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].touched}" *ngIf="addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].hasError('required') && addHotelMappingAmenities.controls['close_time'].touched">Please select Close at.</div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

.ts code is here

```
this.addHotelMappingAmenities = this.formBuilder.group({
      hotel_id: [''],
      title: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern("^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()'?.,|-]+\\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()'?.,|-]+$")])],
      contact_number: ['', Validators.required],
      open_time: [''],
      close_time: [''],
      type: ['', Validators.required],
      image: [''],
      description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(1000), Validators.pattern('^[^ <>\/](([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[^<>\/])*[^<>\/ ]+$')])],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always can use a customValidator about all the form

```
customValidator(openTimeKey: string, closeTimeKey: string) {
    return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
      let openTime: number = group.controls[openTimeKey].value;
      let closeTime: number = group.controls[closeTimeKey].value;
      let errorExist=(openTime && !closeTime) || (!openTime && closeTime);
      return errorExist?{error:'must choosen two or none"}:null;
    }
```

then, when you define the form builder

```
this.addHotelMappingAmenities = this.formBuilder.group({
      hotel_id: [''],
      ...
      },{ validator: this.customValidator('openTime', 'closeTime') });
```