# Angular 4 reactive forms custom validator returns TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: forms, angular, function

I have a custom validator to evaluate 2 controller values; totalDisch should be more than damaNumb

> NumberValidator

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidator {
    static invalidDama(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        //safety check
        if (!c.get('damaNumb').value || !c.get('totalDisch').value) return null;

       if (c.get('damaNumb').value < c.get('totalDisch').value)
            return { invalidDama: true }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> The html template

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="damaNumb">DAMA Number:</label>
                        <input type="number" formControlName="damaNumb" id="damaNumb" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter DAMA Number (1-100)" [(ngModel)]="damaNumb" [min]="1" [max]="100" />
                        <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').touched && form.get('damaNumb').invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                            <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').errors.required">DAMA Number is required....</div>
                            <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').errors.min">Minimum "1"....</div>
                            <div *ngIf="form.get('damaNumb').errors.max">Maximum "100"....</div>
                        </div>




      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="totalDisch">Total Discharges:</label>
                <input type="number" formControlName="totalDisch" id="totalDisch" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Total Discharges (1-100)" [(ngModel)]="totalDisch" [min]="1" [max]="100" />
                <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').touched && form.get('totalDisch').invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                    <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.required">Total Discharges is required....</div>
                    <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.min">Minimum "1"....</div>
                    <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.max">Maximum "100"....</div>
                    <div *ngIf="form.get('totalDisch').errors.invalidDama">Discharges can not be less than DAMA....</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

> Component file:

```
form = new FormGroup({
        hospital: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
        department: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        damaDt: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        damaNumb: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        totalDisch: new FormControl('',[
            Validators.required,
            NumberValidator.invalidDama
        ]),
        notes: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(125))
    } );
```

when the page is loaded i get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Any help?
Thank you in advance............

> I was able to raise the error when totalDisch is less than damaNumb with the function in the same component file outside the call

```
export function invalidDama(c: AbstractControl) {
    //safety check

    if (!c.get('damaNumb').value || !c.get('totalDisch').value) {return { c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors(null) } }

    if (c.get('damaNumb').value < c.get('totalDisch').value)
    { return { c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors(null) } }
    return { c: c.get('totalDisch').setErrors({ invalidDama: true }) };
}
```

> the form group is modified:

```
 form = new FormGroup({
        hospital: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required),
        department: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        damaDt: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        damaNumb: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        totalDisch: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        notes: new FormControl('', Validators.maxLength(125))
    },  invalid
```

> However, the form is always Disable (the submit button) even if the form is valid................?

Comment: May be this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129719/angular-4-form-validators-minlength-maxlength-does-not-work-on-field-type-nu

Comment: the validator it not about totalDish, it's about the form check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324119/angular-2-validation-on-hotel-amenity-open-time-and-close-time/47324403#47324403 You can make a validator about totalDish, but you need pass as argumento the value of damaNumb

Comment: Thank for reply, still not work and no validatino error

Comment: I was able to raise the errro when totalDisch is less than damaNumb with